# How to update dynamically an object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

I've got an object and I want to update it with new data. But, if one of the keys has a value of `undefined`, I want it to have the same value it was priorly defined.

```
let obj 

obj = {
  name: 'Bill'
  job: 'dev'
  age: 22
}

const newObj = {
  name: 'Sam',
  age: 33
}

Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
  obj[key] = newObj[key];
});
```

I want `obj` to return:

```
{
  name: "Sam"
  job:'dev',
  age: 33,

}
```

But it returns:

```
{
  age: 33,
  job: undefined,
  name: "Sam"
}
```

Also, it would help to return in the same order as the original.

Comment: Check `if(key in newObj)` before updating

Comment: 472

The iteration order for objects follows a certain set of rules since ES2015, but it does not (always) follow the insertion order. Simply put, the iteration order is a combination of the insertion order for strings keys, and ascending order for number-like keys.

Comment: @adiga - It could still exist and have the value `undefined`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply merge the objects using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) like:

```js
let obj 

obj = {
  name: 'Bill',
  job: 'dev',
  age: 22,
}

const newObj = {
  name: 'Sam',
  age: 33,
}

obj= {...obj, ...newObj}
console.log( obj )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
 obj[key] = newObj[key] ? newObj[key] : obj[key];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let obj 

obj = {
  name: 'Bill',
  job: 'dev',
  age: 22
}

const newObj = {
  name: 'Sam',
  age: 33
}

obj= {
  ...obj,
  ...newObj
}
```

Spread will solve your problem. newObject properties will override object properties. (same properties for override)